# TNS:permission denied : ORA-12546 in RHEL 8

Tags: php, linux, oracle, oci8, rhel8

I created a DB connection test in PHP to connect to a remote oracle database. But it's throwing errors like

```
      Failed to connect to Oracle
      Array ( [code] => 12546 [message] => ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied [offset] => 0 [sqltext] => )


      **CODE**

$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1567))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))";     
$conn=oci_connect("username","pwd",$db);

If (!$conn)
    echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
 
else
    echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';
 $e = oci_error();   // For oci_connect errors pass no handle
 oci_close($conn);
```

Oracle instaclient path **/usr/lib/oracle/19.11/client64/lib**

oci8 path **/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8**

Any clue to solve this error?

**FEW INFORMATION**

```
       Installed packages
       PHP 7.2
       php-ldap
       php-cli
       php-gd
       php-pear 
       php-odbc
       php-common 
       php-xml
       php-pdo
       php-process
       php-mbstring
       oci8
       oracle-instantclient-19.11
       oracle-instantclient-devel-19.11
       oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-19.11
```

All these packages are on remote server. I didn't set any variables yet but I gave 755 permission to oracle-instantclient lib oci8.so file.

Comment: Can you update your question with info about what you installed and where?  Is PHP on a remote computer or on the same machine as the DB?  What format is your connect string - is it a simple name (i.e a network alias), or is it the full connect descriptor (with lots of parentheses), or is it 'Easy Connect' syntax (like "my_hostname/my_service_name")?  Does your PHP process have read permissions on the tnsnames.ora file?  What Oracle environment variables like ORACLE_HOME, TNSADMIN etc do you have set?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Hello, I added a few more details to my question. Could you please look into this.

Comment: Can anything connect to that remote database?  Does SQL\*Plus connect?

Comment: SQL Plus also doesn't connect

Comment: From googling, it sounds like a problem on the database side.  Check with your DBA that the Oracle Network listener was started correctly and can actually access the tnsnames.ora file in the DB software installation.

Comment: sqlplus is working now. But what am I doing wrong in PHP code?

Comment: You probably need to make sure the same environment variables used by SQL*Plus are set in the web server configuration files.

Comment: @ChristopherJones this is solved

Answer (score 0):

I added tnsnames.ora at this path ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. Added following connection string and voila it's working for me

```
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1567))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))
```

This solution helped me to solve this issue. Maybe it will help you also.

Answer (score 0):

When the SELinux service is active on your Linux server, the Apache server cannot connect to services running outside of the server. For this reason, you must change this configuration by executing the following command:

```
    setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

This command helped me to solve this issue.